# Python Tkinter - How to make new_window popup run consecutively (one after the other) instead of making all the new_windows pop up at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

Here's a snippet of the print_output function:

```
def print_output(textinput, width, height, level):
    new_window = Toplevel(level)
    new_window.geometry("{}x{}".format(width, height))
    new_window.title("")
    new_window.config(bg="black")
    label2 = Label(new_window, text=textinput, bg="black", fg="red")
    label2.grid(row=0, column=0)
    button10 = Button(new_window, text="Ok", width = 5, font="System 20", bg="red", fg="black", activebackground="black", activeforeground="red", borderwidth=5, cursor="hand2", highlightthickness=0, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black", command=lambda: new_window.destroy())
    button10.grid(row=1, column=0)

    
print_output("File shortcut created!", 300, 100, root)
print_output("Clock shortcut created!", 300, 100, root)
```

When I run my code, both the "File shortcut created" and "Clock shortcut created" window pops up at the same time. What I want is for the new_window popups to run consecutively so that AFTER the user presses "Ok" button for "File shortcut created" popup it will display "Clock shortcut created!" popup, rather than displaying them both at the same time.

What can I add to my print_output function to wait for user to press Ok button before I can display another print_output funtion?

Comment: Add `new_window.wait_window()` after `button10.grid`.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is for the new_window popups to run consecutively so that
> AFTER the user presses "Ok" button for "File shortcut created" popup
> it will display "Clock shortcut created!" popup, rather than
> displaying them both at the same time.

The problem can be fixed.

Create new `another_window()` function inside `print_output`

In Button widget command change from this `command=lambda: new_window.destroy()`  to `command=lambda: another_window()`

Code:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

def print_output(textinput, width, height, level):
    new_window = Toplevel(level)
    new_window.geometry("{}x{}".format(width, height))
    new_window.title("File shortcut created!")
    new_window.config(bg="black")
    label2 = Label(new_window, text=textinput, bg="black", fg="red")
    label2.grid(row=0, column=0)
    button10 = Button(new_window, text="Ok", width = 5, font="System 20",
                      bg="red", fg="black", activebackground="black",
                      activeforeground="red", borderwidth=5, cursor="hand2",
                      highlightthickness=0, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black",
                      command=lambda: another_window())
    button10.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def another_window():
        print_output("Clock shortcut created!", 300, 100, root)
        new_window.destroy()
           
print_output("File shortcut created!", 300, 100, root)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]